# Firebase realtime database returning an empty array in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty inexperienced in using Firebase, so sorry in advance if some of the code is dumb.

I'm trying to render data from a realtime database of firebase. The problem appears when I try to pass the data to a useState constant and when try to console.log the useState variable it returns an empty array.

This is the code i'm using:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Contador from "../components/Partida/Contador";
import { database } from "../src/config/fb";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Partida = () => {
  const [datos, setDatos] = useState([]);

  const retrieveDocs = async () => {
    try {
      const matchCol = collection(database, "Partida");
      const data = await getDocs(matchCol);
      const result = data.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      setDatos(result);
      console.log(datos);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveDocs();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.pantalla}>
      <Text></Text>
      <Contador />
      <Contador />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pantalla: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default Partida;
```

The thing is that when I update this code, it reads the file from the beginnig and gives me a corrent log on the console, so in some way I understand where the problem is, but I have no Idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you make a change on the code, the screen will be rendered, causing the `useEffect` hook to be called and retrieve the docs again. That is expected behavior, similar to what happens when the user restarts the app.

Comment: Yeah I know, the thing is that on the first render "datos" const returns an undefined parameter, and I don't want that to happen.